# Calling Another user control from one user control

Tags: c#

I have two user controls usercontrol_1 and usercontrol_2, using a click event i am bring in usercontrol_1 to a panel called panel_screen on my main form.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!panel_screen.Controls.Contains(usercontrol_1.Instance))
            {
                panel_screen.Controls.Add(usercontrol_1.Instance);
                usercontrol_1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                usercontrol_1.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
                usercontrol_1.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
```

Similarly i wanna bring usercontrol_2 to the same panel on the main form using a button (click event) on usercontrol_1. 
How do i do this? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what problem are you facing here? and what is `usercontrol_1.Instance`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are having problem, I think the way you are using `usercontrol_1.Instance` might cause the issue.

I have working example here, you can try it.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool userControlIsAlreadyInPanel = false;

    //assuming you are cheking if usercontrol_1 is already there on panel
    // you don't want to create new usercontrol, but just bring existing control to the front
    foreach(UserControl control in panel_screen.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(usercontrol_1))
        {
            userControlIsAlreadyInPanel = true;
            control.BringToFront();
        }
    }

    if(!userControlIsAlreadyInPanel)
    {
        usercontrol_1 instane = new usercontrol_1();

        panel_screen.Controls.Add(instane);
        instane.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        instane.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
        public delegate void MyEventDelegate(object sender, string name);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    usercontrol_1 _ctrl1 = null;
    usercontrol_2 _ctrl2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _ctrl1 = new usercontrol_1();
        _ctrl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _ctrl1.userControlButtonClicked += userControlButtonClicked;
        _ctrl2 = new usercontrol_2();
        _ctrl2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _ctrl2.userControlButtonClicked += userControlButtonClicked;
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControlButtonClicked(_ctrl1, "1");
    }

    private void userControlButtonClicked(object sender, string name)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        if (sender.Equals(_ctrl1))
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(_ctrl2);
        }
        else if (sender.Equals(_ctrl2))
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(_ctrl1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
public partial class usercontrol_1 : UserControl
{
    public event MyEventDelegate userControlButtonClicked;
    public usercontrol_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyEventDelegate med = userControlButtonClicked;
        if (med != null)
        {
            med(this, "1");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
public partial class usercontrol_2 : UserControl
{
    public event MyEventDelegate userControlButtonClicked;
    public usercontrol_2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyEventDelegate med = userControlButtonClicked;
        if (med != null)
        {
            med(this, "2");
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for why your post answers the question alongside the code